# Converting Apache RewriteRule to Nginx Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I’m completely new to Nginx, and I’ve wrote this Apache code which I used to put into a `.htaccess` file, and I’m stumped on converting it to Nginx. I know which `.conf` file to put it in, but ave no clue how to write this syntax.

Please advise.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On nginx this is :

```
# nginx configuration

location / {
  rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9 /-]+)$ profile.php?profile_username=$1;
  rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9 /-]+)/$ profile.php?profile_username=$1;
}
```

Comment: If you have another htaccess to convert for nginx go on this site : http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Comment: Well I was having a issue with this, I already had a default location file, that is uneditable due to EasyEngine. Nginx was giving me an error stating, "nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in" when I created my new file. So from documentation it said to put ^~ instead of / after location. Is this correct? I don't believe it is due to my website not rewriting.

From documentation